# Self referral in Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, referrer

I use Google Adwowrds and Analytics for my website, when I check, as the main source of sessions, is shown paid searches (adwords), but Google Analytics shows that most of the referrals for transactions (Purchases) from my own website. 
There are two possible reasons for this in my situation. Cross Domain Tracking and Page Dropping Cookie.
Regarding Cross Domain Tracking, I use single domain, but after the customer checks out, the Thank You page comes with Shopify domain, can it be considered that I use multiple domain?

Regarding the Cookie Drop out, how can I find it out? and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user moves from one domain (your domain) to another domain (the Shopify domain) then a new Google Analytics cookie is generated and this cookie has a difference client ID stored in it for Google Analytics. So even if the Shopify domain is sending data to the same Google Analytics property, since the client ID is different, Google Analtyics will treat this as a new user and a new session and in the eyes of Google Analytics, this session will be a referral from the first domain (your website).

If you want to prevent this from happening, you must implement cross-domain tracking which you can read about [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood it now, but in the link , Google says, as the 3rd step, Edit the tracking code on the secondary domain. In my case secondary domain is Shopify, as Google says The tracking code snippet must contain these changes every place it appears on your secondary domain. But, I cant control the domain of Shopify or PayPal, so what can I do"?

Comment: If you don't control the source code of the second domain (Shopify) then there's nothing you can do. In this case you should just make sure to add the Shopify domain to your referral exclusion list (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en) so that the original​ source/medium of the user doesn't get overwritten when they come back to your site after visiting Shopify.

Comment: If this helped, could you please accept the answer? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah it helped, called Google, they suggested same. Although I excluded, I see that time by time, still there are some that again come with self referrals or shopify, but now less.

Comment: It will take some time for the referrals to drop to zero because of the way attribution works in GA. Eventually they will disappear though. Thanks for accepting the answer.